# Showing $f\notin \overline{S[a,b]}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebras

> Let $f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{ for } 0<x\leq 1\\
> 0 \text{ for } x=0
> \end{cases}$
>
> Show $f\notin \overline{S[0,1]}$, where $S[a,b]$ denotes the set of all step functions on the interval $[a,b]$, and the overline denotes the closure.

Thoughts/Remarks:

- $S[0,1]$ is a subalgebra of $B[0,1]$ (all bounded functions on the interval $[0,1] )$
- $f$ is bounded and hence $f\in B[0,1]$
- $\overline{S[a,b]}$ is a closed set
- The right and left handed limits of $f$ exist at every point $x\in[a,b]$ in order for $f$ to be in the closure of $S[a,b]$, so maybe a proof by contradiction might work. Something along the lines of: Suppose $f\in \overline{S[a,b]}.$ Then the right and left handed limits of $f$ exists at every point in our interval. Then showing that a certain limit doesn't exist would conclude the proof, but I'm not sure how to go about finding which limit fails to exist. Presumably it'd be where the functions differ, since $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is continuous and so is the zero function. So probably the limit that fails is at $x=0 \text{ (from the right side)}$

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, which doesn't exist since it oscillates infinitely from the right as we approach zero.

Not sure if this is a good enough. I feel like I am not being rigorous enough. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Dense with respect to what topology?

Comment: My book has never talked about topologies, so if there's a normal, usual or standard typology, then that's the one.

Comment: Does your book mention a norm or mode of convergence?

Comment: I think the sup norm is the norm. $\sup_{x\in X} |f(x)|=||f||_{\infty}$ That's the norm we used for $C(X)$ and  $B(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any step function is of the form
$$
s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\,\chi_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}(x),
$$
where $0=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=1$ is a partition of $[\,0,1\,]$ and $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$. Then
$$
\sup_{0\le x\le1}|f(x)-s(x)|\ge\sup_{0\le x\le x_1}|\sin\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)-a_1|\ge\min(|a_1|,|1-a_1|)>0.
$$

Comment: I'm a little new with step functions. If we can show that $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f(x)-s(x)|>1$, we are showing that $f$ does not converge uniformly to $s$ ( I think). But why would this mean that $f$ is not in the closure of $S[a,b]$? Is it something to do with showing that it is outside an epsilon ball?

Comment: If $f$ is in the closure of the set of step functions, then there is a sequence of step functions converging uniformly (in the $\sup$ norm) to $f$. What I have shown is that no sequence of step functions converges to $f$.